# Send messages to multiple passed recipients or a default recipient

Tags: php

I have a function that accepts false as a default value but can be passed an array.

```
protected function sendMessages ($recipients = false) {

    //cast to an array
    $recipients = is_array($recipients) ? $recipients : [$recipients];

    // if no recipients are passed get email from current object (default)
    if (isset($recipients[0]) && $recipients[0] === false) {
        array_pop($recipients);
        array_push($recipients, 'email' => $this->author->email);
    }

    foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
        //some logic.
    }
}
```

The whole, check if the first element is false, and if so swap it out seems a little convoluted / backwards to me. But I'm not sure of a cleaner method. The default value could be changed but is needed so that older calls to the method that specify no parameters don't choke.

Comment: Closed due to the syntactically invalid code (illegal use of `this`) and the title that asks about a practice rather than stating the purpose of the code. (See the [ask] guidelines.)

Comment: $this was a typo. Seems harsh to close it for an obvious typographical error.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. Ask a new question instead, incorporating the feedback you've already received.

Comment: That's the point of Code Review. We have to be precise.

Comment: Also, next time, please don't post code containing `some logic`. Post the real code instead or risk getting your new question closed as well.

Comment: So you'd rather I reposted with the typo corrected?

Comment: I've made an exception to the rule and allowed your edit to the question and answer. (Please take care to post real working code in the future, though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
protected function sendMessages (array $recipients = []) {

    // if no recipients are passed get email from current object (default)
    if ( ! $recipients) {
        array_push($recipients, 'email' => $this->author->email);
    }

    foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
        //some logic.
    }
}
```

Assuming you can change the default value, an empty array evaluates as `false`: https://3v4l.org/Onpcv (alternatively if you don’t like using it like that, do a check on the `count`, or `empty` etc)